# How to open a default workspace when launching Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, workspace

Software : Visual Studio Code

OS : macOS 10.14

Version : 1.28.2 (1.28.2)

I have a folder that I work on every time with VSC, no other requirements.
I want to open this folder as a folder/workspace by default on launch of VSC so that I don't have to browse through and open that workspace again.
How can I change settings/ write a script so that when I launch VSC, that workspace opens up automatically.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the settings

```
"files.hotExit": "onExitAndWindowClose"
"window.restoreWindows": "folders"
```

Note if you launch VSC by a file in explorer, it will not open the file in your current workspace and the workspace information will be lost (you'll have to open the workspace manually again on saving)

Comment: Note if you launch VSC by a file in explorer, it will not open the file in your current workspace and the workspace information will be lost (you'll have to open the workspace manually again on saving) - Can this behavior be corrected?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the setting of `window.restoreWindows` to `preserve` :

[image: Settings : restoreWindows]

This will reopen your workspace even if you open a file and Visual Studio code is not already opened on your workspace.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I wanted -- The only workspace I use is my "PowerShell" folder, occasionally I create .ps1 files outside this location and VS code opens these in orphaned windows, if I try to open my 'normal' workspace it closes the file I just opened (not helpful!)... Your suggestion keeps my "PowerShell" folder/workspace regardless of which file I edit, where it is stored, or whether I open this from the cmd line, file or explorer or any other way, perfect! 

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the path of `.code-workspace` file as an argument to `code`.

```
code /path/to/your.code-workspace
```

You may just update your default Code shortcut based on this.