# How to open a default folder when launching Visual Studio Code on newly provisioned machines?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

How can I change settings.json (or whatever) so that when I launch VSC, that a workspace (or literally just a directory) opens up automatically.

I have already reviewed this other great answer [How to open a default workspace when launching Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105535/how-to-open-a-default-workspace-when-launching-visual-studio-code)

However I need to do this on brand new, newly provisioned machines that are ephemeral (meaning they get destroyed and recreated from scratch).  That means that simply memorizing what I did once, does not help.

Also.... is there a way to do the same thing where the integrated terminal is already open as well?  I can't seem to find knobs for either of the above in the settings.json.

This is on linux servers that students will open in their web browser using vs code server.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Also, what mechanism are you using to provision VSC on these machines?